# How to find out the number of redundant rows in a data frame and report this number as a separate column

Tags: python, pandas

Having a data frame that looks like this:

```
Col1     Col2     Col3
A         B        C
C         D        E
F         G        H
A         B        C
A         H        K
A         B        C
F         G        H
A         B        C
```

I need to find the each repeated pattern, count it, and report it in an extra column, the output would then be:

```
Col1     Col2     Col3     Count
A         B        C         4
C         D        E         1
F         G        H         2
A         B        C         4
A         H        K         1
A         B        C         4
F         G        H         2
A         B        C         4
```

The idea that I have is to use the size of th original data frame and the size after dropping duplicates making use of the df.drop_duplicates, but I wonder if there is a nice way?

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` and `transform`

```
In [4241]: df['Count'] = df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])['Col1'].transform('size')

In [4242]: df
Out[4242]:
  Col1 Col2 Col3  Count
0    A    B    C      4
1    C    D    E      1
2    F    G    H      2
3    A    B    C      4
4    A    H    K      1
5    A    B    C      4
6    F    G    H      2
7    A    B    C      4
```

---

Or, alternative use of `merge`

```
In [4256]: df.merge(df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']).size().reset_index(name='Count'),
                    how='left')
Out[4256]:
  Col1 Col2 Col3  Count
0    A    B    C      4
1    C    D    E      1
2    F    G    H      2
3    A    B    C      4
4    A    H    K      1
5    A    B    C      4
6    F    G    H      2
7    A    B    C      4
```

Comment: Slightly more general: `df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).Col1.transform('size')`